# How do i configure a task to call a powershell script in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up a build task in visual studio code to call an existing build script written in powershell.
Here is how i set up my build task

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "powershell",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [   
        "-File ${cwd}/source/deployment/build.ps1",
        "-NoProfile",
        "-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"
    ],
    "taskSelector": "-task ",
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "showOutput": "always",
            "isBuildCommand": true
        }
    ]
}
```

but here the output when i run the task

> . : File
>   C:\Users\chkeita\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
>   cannot be loaded because  running scripts is disabled on this system.
>   For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:3
>   + . 'C:\Users\chkeita\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_
>   ...
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
>   -File : The term '-File' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check  the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + -File f:\Dev\spf3/source/deployment/build.ps1 -NoProfile -executionpo ...
>   + ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-File:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I have tried reordering the arguments and merging them in one string without any success

What am i missing? 
Is there a better way to do this in vscode

Comment: Try changing: "-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" to "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"

Comment: And it seems that the path will have to change to: -File ${cwd}\source\deployment\build.ps1; not sure if "-File" is the correct command tbh.

Comment: it doesn't help, these are the paramter the powershell command (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx)
and i tested it in a command line and it works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here is  working version. see the github [discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3519#issuecomment-189688918) for more details

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "powershell",
    "args": [   
        "-ExecutionPolicy",
        "Unrestricted",
        "-NoProfile",
        "-File",
        "${cwd}/source/deployment/build.ps1"       
    ],
    "taskSelector": "-task ",
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "showOutput": "always",
            "isBuildCommand": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: To spell it out: CLI parameters such as `-ExecutionPolicy` and `-NoProfile` must be placed _before_ a `-File` or (possibly implied) `-Command` argument in order to be effective. Otherwise they are considered arguments to the script file being invoked / part of the command to execute.